# Solving 1D PDE Heat Equation By Separation Of Variables, Boundary Conditions Not Equal To Zero

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a PDE heat equation question, but the boundary conditions are not equal to zero and it is giving me trouble, especially as all examples I can find online are of PDEs where the boundary conditions are zero. Here is the question:

A bar of  metal of  length $\pi$ lies along the x-axis.

$$ u_t = \kappa^2u_{xx}\\ u(0, t) = T_1, u(\pi,t)=T_2 $$

Now I follow the steps I am used to where we assume it is separable

$$ \dfrac{X''}{X} = \dfrac{T'}{k^2T}=\lambda $$

Solve $X'' = \lambda X$

Try $\lambda = n^2 > 0$

Usually, when the boundary conditions are that the ends are both 0, this leads to a trivial solution where $X(x) = 0$ so we try $\lambda = 0$ which also leads to a trivial solution so then it must be $\lambda = -n^2 <0$ which then leads to an interesting result. However with the boundary conditions of $T_1$ and $T_2$ we get:

$$ X''=-n^2X \\ X= Ae^{nx} + Be^{-nx} \\ X(0) = T_1 \rightarrow A + B = T_1 \\ 
X(\pi) = T_2 \rightarrow Ae^{\pi x}+Be^{-\pi x} = T_2$$

And then we just have a system of equations for A and B which is consistent so we can't rule out the possibility that $ \lambda = n^2 >0$?

Comment: Use $u_{p}(x,t) = T_{1}+x(T_{2}-T_{1})/\pi$ is a particular solution, note if you substitute $u(x,t)=u_{p}(x,t)+v(x,t)$, you will find $v(x,t)$ must satisfy the PDE with homogeneous (zero) boundary conditions, find $v(x,t)$ and substitute back to find $u(x,t)$.

Comment: @Tucker Thank-you! Yes that makes sense, follow up question, how would you prove that the solution space to this PDE doesn't form a vector space?

Comment: $u(0,t) =T_{1}$, $v(0,t)=T_{1}$, $w(x,t)=u(x,t)+v(x,t)$ will not satisfy the boundary condition at $x=0$ provided $T_{1}$ is nonzero.